# How do I check if any checkboxes at all on the page are checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check, using jQuery, if any checkboxes on the page are checked. The particular checkbox set they are contained in doesn't matter, just any of them.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`var isChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked");`

or

`var isChecked =  $('input:checkbox').is(':checked')`

Comment: `$('input:checkbox').is(':checked')`

Comment: I think you are both correct, there are multiple ways to accomplish this with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks. I used the second one, and it worked perfectly right away.

Comment: Thanks. I used the first one, and it worked perfectly right away.

Answer (score 5):

The following function returns `true` if there are any ticked checkboxes and `false` otherwise.

```
function anyCheckbox()
{
    var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++)
        if (inputElements[i].type == "checkbox")
            if (inputElements[i].checked)
                return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('checkbox:checked').length > 0)
    //Some checkbox is checked
```

This should find any checkboxes on the page that are checked

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to look at checkboxes, not radio buttons:
var isChecked = $("input:checkbox").is(":checked");

if you're ok with checkboxes or radio buttons:
var isChecked = $("input").is(":checked");

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var ischecked =$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
```

so

```
if (ischecked > 0)
```

then at least one is checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkbox(){
    var ischecked =$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
    if (ischecked <= 0){        // you can change your condition
    alert("No Record Selected");
    return false;
    }else
    {
      -------//your Action that you want
    }

}
```

Comment: **Duplicate of** shanabus answer, don't suggest what is already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modern JS way, without using jQuery:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[type=checkbox]')).some(x => x.checked)
```

It will return true if at least one checkbox is checked, false otherwise.